# Equivalent of millis() in Atmel studio

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, atmel-studio

This code It works in atmel studio.But this millis function is starting to run 31-34 miliseconds behind of arduino millis fuction.Why?I am adding picture.

**Picture**: https://imageshack.com/a/img922/3060/umtNJp.jpg

**Update 2**

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>

#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define clockCyclesToMicroseconds(a) ( ((a) * 1000L) / (F_CPU / 1000L) )
#define MICROSECONDS_PER_TIMER0_OVERFLOW (clockCyclesToMicroseconds(64 * 256))
#define MILLIS_INC (MICROSECONDS_PER_TIMER0_OVERFLOW / 1000)
// the fractional number of milliseconds per timer0 overflow. we shift right
// by three to fit these numbers into a byte. (for the clock speeds we care
// about - 8 and 16 MHz - this doesn't lose precision.)
#define FRACT_INC ((MICROSECONDS_PER_TIMER0_OVERFLOW % 1000) >> 3)
#define FRACT_MAX (1000 >> 3)
volatile unsigned long timer0_overflow_count = 0;
volatile unsigned long timer0_millis = 0;
static unsigned char timer0_fract = 0;

volatile uint8_t count;

ISR (TIMER0_OVF_vect)

{


    unsigned long m = timer0_millis;
    unsigned char f = timer0_fract;

    m += MILLIS_INC;
    f += FRACT_INC;
    if (f >= FRACT_MAX) {
        f -= FRACT_MAX;
        m += 1;
    }

    timer0_fract = f;
    timer0_millis = m;
    timer0_overflow_count++;





}

unsigned long millis()
{
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

    // disable interrupts while we read timer0_millis or we might get an
    // inconsistent value (e.g. in the middle of a write to timer0_millis)
    cli();
    m = timer0_millis;
    SREG = oldSREG;

    return m;
}



int main (void)

{
    DDRB |= (1<<0); 
    TCNT0 = 0;
    count = 0;
    TCCR0B |= (0<<CS02) | (1<<CS01) | (1<<CS00); // PRESCALER 64
    TIMSK0 = (1<<TOIE0);
    sei();

    while(1)  
    {
        millis() to uart.

    }

}
```

Comment: cross post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780848/using-of-millis-in-atmel-studio

Answer (score 4):

The `millis()` function is defined in the [Arduino Core for AVR architecture](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr), specifically the [`wiring.c` file](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring.c).

You can see that timer0 is setup with various parameters for prescaling and interrupt triggering and handling of timer0 overflow such that a variable called `timer0_millis` contains the number of milliseconds since the sketch started.

The `millis()` function basically returns that `timer0_millis` value.

If you wish to make use of the function in AVR Studio, then you would need to include the same kind of timer0 setup and interrupt/overflow handling that the Arduino core does.

Comment: I have found example code,but isn't same.Can you write equivalent of code in above?for being example and my learning.Of course,If is this possible?Thanks.

Comment: I will not write it for you. It's already written in wiring.c

Comment: oh sorry,I hadn't seen wiring.c file.I have added to my project.But I am not using timer0_millis.Error: 'timer0_millis' undeclared (first use in this function).

What can I add wiring.c to my project?

Comment: You will need to read all of wiring.c, understand it, and then implement it in your own project. Arduino makes very simple the things which are complex on "pain" AVR programming. What is the reason you choose to use AVR Studio?

Comment: Because I am learning atmel studio.But now,I need to this function.No need to make it so difficult.Just,I want to counter like millis() which has forward direction.I need solution.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk about it, but there is A LOT of complexity and options that are simplified by Arduino. In my answer, I said that millis() basically returns timer0_millis, however, that variable gets its value from an overflow-triggered interrupt service routine. There is no "just give code" answer -- to learn AVR Studio means to learn AVR architecture. Fortunately, wiring.c and the files it includes contain all you need to be able to implement millis() in your own project.

Comment: If wiring.c is enough for millis then you can give me code.just,copy and paste bro.I promise learn how is it work.But now,I really need.And I am trying to run part of wiring.c,I don't still run.Good days.

Comment: Asking for users to just give you code isn't a good way to get anything, especially an understanding of how it should work

Comment: You already got your answer @alexjla, it is time to study now, if you want to learn

Comment: @alexjla, I gave you on SO a link to AVR forum. there is the code https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/907712#comment-907712